# Uniqueness of the sum of $n$ prime numbers in a range

Tags: prime-numbers

Let's say that I want to calculate the sum of 20 prime numbers that reside in the range up to 1000. Will the sum (addition, not multiplication) of any 20 primes in that range be unique , or will I see recurrences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $3+13=5+11$, so you have no uniqueness.

P.S. Note that by looking at [A045917](https://oeis.org/A045917), you can even find 40 distinct primes $p_1,\dots, p_{40}$ such that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{20}p_k=\sum_{k=21}^{40}p_k.$$
For example the sum of
$$3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 239$$
is equal to the sum of 
$$37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 109, 113, 211, 227.$$

Comment: Thank you. Multiplications will yield unique results in such case, correct? that is, if any of the 20 prime numbers is used only once

Comment: @azer Yes because any integer has a unique factorization.